# Get values from either Gyroscope or Accelerometer

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, accelerometer, gyroscope

I am trying to build an application wherein I need only the device rotation values. I want the application support to be as low as possible, so my preference would be to read the values from Gyroscope first if the device has its hardware (iPhone 4) or get the values from Accelerometer (iPhone 3G & 3GS).

I would like to write a RotationManager class which would handle interacting with either Gyroscope or Accelerometer, its internal operation will be abstract for the rest of the application. How do I design the RotationManager class? What are the things that should be considered in order to build a good reusable RotationManager instance?

Thanks,

Raj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple's Core Motion framework already does that job for you. Using the `CMMotionManager`, you can opt to receive accelerometer and gyroscope events separately or register for combined device motion events that automatically uses all the hardware that is available on the user's device.

Comment: Ok, but how do I get rotation events in iPhone 3G or iPhone 3GS since it doesnt has Gyro?

Comment: In most cases, it is not possible to detect device rotation with the accelerometer alone. Have you even tried what data the Core Motion framework generates for you on a non-gyro device? I doubt you or I can do a better job than Apple's engineers.

Comment: Yes agreed, for now I am depending on CMAttitude to give me the information needed.